# counting the sequences of 0s in binary number

Tags: java, string, binary, sequence

```
package com.company;

public
class ToBinary
    {
        public String convertToBinary( int n)
            {
                return Integer.toBinaryString( n );
            }
        public int howMany(int number)
        {
            String x = convertToBinary(number);
            char[] y = x.toCharArray();
            int counter=0; //how many seq in binary number
            /*
                sequence counts if 0s are surrounded by 1 f.ex 101 1001 is 1 sequence
                                                               100100101 is 3 seq
                                                               1010 is 1 seq
             */
            int temp=0;
            int maxGlobal=0;
            int maxLocal =0;
            for(int i=1;i<y.length-1;i++)
                {
                    if(y[i]!=y[i-1] && y[i]!=y[i+1])
                        counter++;
                    if(y[i]==0 && y[i-1]==0)
                        {
                            maxLocal +=1;
                        }
                    if(y[i]==0 && y[i+1]==1)
                    {
                        maxLocal +=1;
                        maxGlobal= maxLocal;
                        maxLocal =0;
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            System.out.println(maxGlobal);
            return counter;
        }

    }
```

I wrote some code but i don't know what I am doing here wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please specify what problem your having, for example specifying the inputs, the expected outputs and what you're getting instead (wrong results? an exception? anything at all?)

Comment: When it goes with couter, it puts out good number, but results for the longest sequence of 0s in a binary number not. I tried to take notes on a sheet of paper step-by-step, but still I do not know where I am stuck below where I increment counter.

Comment: always it puts out 0 in maxGlobal

Comment: I think one thing you may not have noticed is that you're checking y[i] for values like 0 and 1.. when you should be checking for "0" and "1" since you converted it into a char array.

Comment: Why `1011001` is 1 sequence and `100100101` is three sequences - should be 2 sequences if a minimal count of 0s is 2?

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
String trimmed = convertToBinary(number).replaceAll("0+$","");
return (trimmed.length() - trimmed.replaceAll("10","").length())/2;
```

It doesn't matter how long the sequence is, just that it has a zero in it and isn't at the end of the string.

Comment: It does, because I have a task that says to count how long the longest sequence is and how many are there.

Comment: So do `String[] split = trimmed.split("1+")` and find the string of zeros in the array with the longest length.

Comment: I did it my way, and it worked out. Simple solutions are the best but thanks everyone for help.

Comment: I used just char[x] y = x.toCharArray() and couple for loops, if-statements and while in second part

Answer (score 0):

Instead of debugging parsing logic it may be more convenient to process the input, get rid of irrelevant parts (leading and or trailing zeroes), find valid groups of 0s, define their length and then count the occurrences or find the longest sequence:

- using `String::split` + `String::replaceAll`

```java
private static IntStream toBinary(int n) {
    return Arrays.stream(Integer.toBinaryString(n)
            .replaceAll("(^0+1|10+$)", "1") // remove leading/trailing 0s
            .split("1+")
        ) // Stream<String>
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .filter(i -> i > 1);
}

public static int howManyZeroSeqs(int n) {
    return (int) toBinary(n).count();
}

public static int maxZeroSeqLength(int n) {
    return toBinary(n).max().orElse(0);
}
```

Tests

```java
for (int i : new int[]{0b01001001000100, 0b010010010000100100010000}) {
    System.out.println("#seqs (" + Integer.toBinaryString(i) + ") = " + howManyZeroSeqs(i));
    System.out.println("max length (" + Integer.toBinaryString(i) + ") = " + maxZeroSeqLength(i));
}
```

Output:

```
#seqs (1001001000100) = 3
max length (1001001000100) = 3
#seqs (10010010000100100010000) = 5
max length (10010010000100100010000) = 4
```

---

- use matching pattern to detect sequences of at least 2 zeroes not at the end of the string

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2CTR9/1)

```java
static Pattern ZEROSEQ = Pattern.compile("(?=1(0{2,}+)(?!$))1");
private static IntStream toBinary(int n) {
    return ZEROSEQ.matcher(Integer.toBinaryString(n))
        .results()
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1))
        .mapToInt(String::length);
}
```

`(?=1(0{2,}+)(?!$))1` - `?=1(0{2,}+)` positive lookahead: 1 followed by a capturing group for the sequence of at least 2 zeroes

`(?!$)` - negative lookahead - group of 0s not followed by the end of the string
1 - closing 1

The test results are the same.